# Angular2 with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to follow the steps outlined here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html but can't seem to get a basic hello world working. My project seems to build successfully, but when I point my browser to http://localhost:8080/ I see this error (404) at the last request:

> 16.09.02 00:35:06 200 GET /index.html
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:06 200 GET /app.63d880f68c1209ba2e74.css
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:06 200 GET /app.63d880f68c1209ba2e74.js
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:08 200 GET /polyfills.63d880f68c1209ba2e74.js
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:30 200 GET /app.63d880f68c1209ba2e74.css.map
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:31 200 GET /polyfills.63d880f68c1209ba2e74.js.map
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:31 200 GET /vendor.63d880f68c1209ba2e74.js
>
> 16.09.02 00:35:33 404 GET /`<main>`
>     `<h1>Hello from Angular 2 App with Webpack</h1>`
>     `<img src="/assets/angular.9db278d630f5fabd8e7ba16c2e329a3a.png">`
>   `</main>`

In the console I get the following:

> rozone.js:101 GET http://localhost:8080/%3Cmain%3E%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3EHello%20from%20Angular%202…assets/angular.9db278d630f5fabd8e7ba16c2e329a3a.png%22%3E%0A%3C/main%3E%0A 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:345Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:282(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM62:3ResourceLoaderImpl.get @ platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:131DirectiveNormalizer._fetch @ compiler.umd.js:13450DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync @ compiler.umd.js:13493DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective @ compiler.umd.js:13468RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledTemplate @ compiler.umd.js:16843(anonymous function) @ compiler.umd.js:16781(anonymous function) @ compiler.umd.js:16779RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.umd.js:16778RuntimeCompiler.*compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.umd.js:16715RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.umd.js:16706PlatformRef*.*bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.umd.js:9488PlatformRef*.bootstrapModule @ core.umd.js:9470webpackJsonp.0 @ main.ts:9__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 63d880f…:50webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 63d880f…:21(anonymous function) @ app.63d880f….js:1
>   zone.js:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load %3Cmain%3E%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3EHello%20from%20Angular%202%20App%20with%20Webpack%3C/h1%3E%0A%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22/assets/angular.9db278d630f5fabd8e7ba16c2e329a3a.png%22%3E%0A%3C/main%3E%0A ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load %3Cmain%3E%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3EHello%20from%20Angular%202%20App%20with%20Webpack%3C/h1%3E%0A%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22/assets/angular.9db278d630f5fabd8e7ba16c2e329a3a.png%22%3E%0A%3C/main%3E%0A undefinedconsoleError @ zone.js:484_loop_1 @ zone.js:511drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:515ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:437
>   zone.js:486 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load %3Cmain%3E%0A%20%20%3Ch1%3EHello%20from%20Angular%202%20App%20with%20Webpack%3C/h1%3E%0A%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22/assets/angular.9db278d630f5fabd8e7ba16c2e329a3a.png%22%3E%0A%3C/main%3E%0A(…)consoleError @ zone.js:486_loop_1 @ zone.js:511drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:515ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:437
>   :8080/favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Any help would be greatly appreciated... If you are able to get this to work by following the guide, that also may be helpful as it may mean I somehow failed to enter something in where I was supposed to... Any clues would be great as I have no idea what's going on here... :(

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you tried angular-cli@webpack? It's going to handle webpack configuration for you, so if you just want to get started quickly, I'd suggest having a look. https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: have you build your application with webpack? share your code for it will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @j2L4e. It sounds like a great idea. I did try it just now but the version for webpack doesn't seem to be ready for use yet - I got errors from the ng new command right off the bat and noticed a number of unmet peer dependency errors during the installation. The default (broccoli) version seems to work better at the moment.

Comment: @MrJSingh, I'm just copying the files from the tutorial on the angular web site so I don't think it's worth going to the trouble of pasting them here... I did find one error in tha tutorial already - one needs to do templateUrl: require("<path>") rather than just templateUrl: "<path>" for webpack to catch the dependency so I have a feeling the documentation team has not actually tested that this tutorial for webpack works...

Comment: that is because of tutorial used angular2-template-loader and then you donn't need to use require, you can just templateUrl: "<path>" and angular2-template-loader will take care of it. You can take a look at a seed i created with webpack, it is very simple, nothing complicated.[angular2-webpacj](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed)